# Keeping system in phone correct orientation when disabling 'auto-rotate' in Android

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, autorotate

It looks like a bug in the Android system but i'm note sure :
in my app i use `Settings.System.putInt` to disable auto-rotate, sometimes whenever i fire the command, the orientation changes to another one (and the auto rotate is locked).
I wasn't able to determine to which orientation it will change (sometimes when the phone in portrait and i fire it, it stays in portrait and sometimes changes to landscape, similar thing happens in landscape)
It looks like the orientation in each the application was started in has an effect of the 'target' orientation in each the system will be 'locked' in, but i wasn't able to determine it for sure.
Is anyone aware of this issue ? Anything i can do so it won't happen ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling orientation, set your activity to have a default orientation

for this , go into the manifest
activity tag for the desired activity put this:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

or portrait

and this will make the orientation of your screen to be constant, regardless of the orientation of the device

Comment: I do want to disable the auto-rotate and stay in portrait (or change to portrait if cannot stay this way by setting)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity android:name=".YourFirstActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

if you want to add specifically to one activity

```
   <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"  />
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear enough, i want the app to be in portrait when phone in portrait and landscape when phone in landscape, but whenever i disable the auto-rotate and the phone in landscape, i want it to stay this way and not change to portrait as it currently do. (android default when 'no orientation available')

Comment: To be more clear, are you trying to fire the orientation of the screen even if the user disables `Orientation` in his phone?

Comment: That's the workaround, i would've want the system to stay in landscape mode (if phone in landscape) when auto-rotate is disabled .